# Using SubQueries find the IDs of the users that requested a confirmation message twice within a 24-hour window.(MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HWhx.png)

| user_id | time_stamp | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-27 14:33:06 | timeout |
| 1 | 2020-04-02 08:53:15 | confirmed |
| 1 | 2020-04-12 23:29:44 | confirmed |
| 2 | 2020-05-16 22:20:24 | timeout |
| 2 | 2020-07-06 17:39:03 | timeout |
| 3 | 2020-09-28 06:27:34 | timeout |
| 3 | 2020-01-12 14:54:19 | confired |

I was able to solve using self-join

select distinct c1.user_id
from confirmations c1
join confirmations c2
on c1.user_id=c2.user_id and c1.time_stamp!=c2.time_stamp
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,c1.time_stamp,c2.time_stamp)<= 86400 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,c1.time_stamp,c2.time_stamp)>=0
order by 1;

Answer (score 1):

Using an `exists` subquery to check if any `confirmed` action has a subsequent `confirmed` action within 24 hours:

```
select distinct c.user_id from confirmations c
where c.action = 'confirmed' and exists (select 1 from confirmations c1 
   where c1.user_id = c.user_id and c1.time_stamp > c.time_stamp 
        and c1.time_stamp <= c.time_stamp + interval 24 hour)
```

[Try it online!](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sm0SU0km)

Comment: Ajax1234, Suppose c1.time_stamp is 2020-01-12 and c2.time_stamp is 2020-01-10 then it fails, even though it is more than 24 hrs apart the above condition gives true.  I was able to fix it using BETWEEN condition (and c1.time_stamp BETWEEN c.time_stamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND c.time_stamp) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gannuarjun Please see my recent edit.

Comment: `select distinct c.user_id from confirmations c
where c.action = 'confirmed' and exists (select 1 from confirmations c1 
   where c1.user_id = c.user_id and c1.time_stamp != c.time_stamp 
        and c1.time_stamp BETWEEN c.time_stamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND c.time_stamp)`